# Java j2me get result from running Thread

Tags: multithreading, java-me, parameters, runnable, midp

Hej,

I know how to pass parameters to a Runnable. But when my Thread has run, how to get the result of the process?

```
    class Some implements Runnable
{
    int p;
    int endresult = 0;

    public Some(int param){
       p = param;
    }

    public void run(){
        //do something
        endresult += p;
       //Now how to let the method who executed this runnable know that the result is 2;
    }
}

Some s = new Some(1);
Thread t = new Thread(s);
t.start();
```

when t is finished i want to get the 'endresult' variable;

Comment: Is there really nobody who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for your thread to terminate and then you can get the field value directly:

```
t.join();
y = s.endresult;
```

Comment: Serious, that simple? Ok, i'll try.

Comment: _not working_ how exactly? FWIW the only thing missing in Howard's way seems `volatile` modifier for `endresult` - try it

Answer (score 1):

declare endresult `volatile` and invoke `t.join` after it was started - when t is finished this will get the 'endresult' value